# MathJax on Ghost

Tags: latex, ghost.org

I have been trying to add MathJax to my blog in the "Ghost" platform on the web (*not self hosted*). I followed some tutorials and I did find out that if I add the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [ ["$","$"] ], displayMath: [ ["$$", "$$"] ]}});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script>
```

into the "blog header" (that I find in "settings"->"code injection") MathJax works fine for displayed math formulas written between `$$`. On the other hand there is no way to have the inline math rendered: it doesn't work with the code `$...$`, `(...)` and `[...]`. What am I doing wrong?

[Here](http://thoughtexplorer.ghost.io/p/527bf5b2-3614-4a0a-be85-c41118e7f51e/) is my test post on the platform.

Answer (score 0):

The current official way to enable MathJax client-side, per [their website](https://www.mathjax.org/#gettingstarted), is to insert the following code into your header:

```
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
<script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>
```

In Ghost, that's done with the "Inject code" functionality.

There's a choice to be made here: if you only use MathJax in a few posts, use the posts' own "Inject code" functionality. That way, it will only load on pages where it's needed, saving other users (and the MathJax servers) the bandwidth.

---

Regarding the syntax, the `$$...$$` and `$...$` syntax is pure TeX, and thus isn't generally recommended for LaTeX anyway (see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to) on TeX.SE for reference).

To render properly, one should use the `\(...\)` syntax for inline math, and `\[...\]` or `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}` for displayed math.

Tested on MathJax 3 and Ghost 3.40.2.