# Using delimiter $$ on its own line no longer works in MathJAX 3.x with Blogger

Tags: blogger, latex, blogger-themes

I've previously used MathJax 2.x on Google's Blogger platform, inserting the library and configuration references in the site's template HTML, as per many recommendations here and elsewhere.

On a new Blogger blog, I decided to use MathJAX 3, using the call that always pulls in the latest 3.x version.

In both cases I use dollar symbols, $ and $$, to trigger inline and display maths.

With MathJax 3.x, I can no longer use $$ on it's own line. The following doesn't work.

```
$$
x=y
$$
```

I need to do this:

```
$$ x = y $$
```

The first is cleaner, especially for multiline equations.

Anyone know how to make this work with MathJAX 3.x?

Here is my config code:

```
<script>
    MathJax = {
      tex: {
        inlineMath: [[&#39;$&#39;, &#39;$&#39;]],
        displayMath: [[&#39;$$&#39;,&#39;$$&#39;]]
      },
      svg: {
        fontCache: &#39;global&#39;
      },
      options: {
        enableMenu: false
      }
    };
    </script>
    <script async='async' id='MathJax-script' src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-chtml.js'/>
```

I'm not an expert so there may be something wrong with this. I have spent several hours reading the MathJAX documentation for 3.x and 2.x.

The problems remains if I use the default delimiter characters, so is not related to the $ symbol.

I have tried the config to replace HTML tags with TEX to try to replace the generated

with nothing, but that fails with an error.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you absolutely have to use `$$...$$` for displayed math? I've [just run into](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/98078/mathjax-on-ghost) MathJax, and it worked out of the box using `\[...\]` for displayed math. The latter is [preferable to the former](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to) anyway.